# Dynamically display newly added cards in the right Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm working on this project where I need to fetch data, and display a list of custom designed card component using map. All works fine but when I add a new value to the array, it will create a new card with the values I want but default to start from the left.

Is there a way to make the new ones get added to the right side instead?

**This is how it looks right now**
[image]

**This is how I want it to look (expected)**
[image]

It could also start from index 0 from the right side if that would solve the problem.

Please note that I have already tried to set the direction to RTL but that doesn't solve the problem of how `map` insert and display new items in the list

**Sample code**

```js
//fetch data 
function fetchData(){
return data.cards.slice().sort(a, b).(a.toUpperCase()< b.toUpperCase() ? -1 : 1)) 

}

const cardsList = fetchData()

<CardList> 
{
cardsList.map( card => (

<Card key={card.id}>
{card.name}
</Card>

))
}
</CardList>
```

Comment: Please post your jsx

Comment: This seems to be a styling problem rather than how you map. I would suggest looking into CSS flexbox. specifically flex-wrap: wrap; and justify-content: flex-end;

Comment: Hello @kiranvj I have added a sample code that you can refer to, this is the basic general idea. I can't share the actual code as it's a private repo. Thanks

Comment: Flex capabilities of css should help you. Have a look here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: But when you add the 4th one you want it to lay on the left of the 3rd one, and so on? If so you need to use flex-order manually.

Comment: Thanks everyone, it was indeed a styling issue.

Comment: @CesarePolonara I want to always display the list from the right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what is `CardList` and `Card` component. But this should be possible with `display:flex`, `flex-wrap` and `justify-content: flex-end;` as in below example.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 450px;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.card {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">index 0</div>
  <div class="card">index 1</div>
  <div class="card">index 2</div>
  <div class="card">index 3</div>
  <div class="card">index 4</div>

</div>
```